# gruntjs vs yeoman vs guard

Tags: ruby, node.js, guard, gruntjs, yeoman

I am currently using guard to watch changes on my .coffee and .scss files and compile them appropriately.

Now, gruntjs and yeoman offer similar features.

1. What would be the incentives to move away from guard to gruntjs or yeoman?
2. What are the benefits of using yeoman vs gruntjs or vice versa?

Thanks!

Comment: FYI, Yeoman is built on top of Grunt.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I understand it manages the configuration under the hood. Is Yeoman then just command line interface more friendly than grunt? I mean it's opiniated and recommend certain ways of doing things. But besides this ... ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They have entirely different purposes.

Guard is comparable with the grunt task [grunt-contrib-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) which runs tasks when files changes.

Grunt is a task based build tool which abstracts the boring work into reusable tasks so you don't have to reinvent the wheel in each project. You can do so much more than just watch for changes. You can concat, minify JS/CSS, compile CoffeeScript/LESS/Sass, etc.

Yeoman builds upon grunt and other tools and provides an opinionated workflow to build front-end web apps. It is much more than just grunt.